# Display values from mysql in month table

Tags: php, mysql, days

I need to display values from mysql table accordingly to day of the month. 
I use the code bellow to display month's days 1-31 but how insert values to exact cell of the day? How this can be achieved?

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("....",".....","...");
if (!$conn) {
echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}
if (!mysql_select_db("roomsbooking")) {
echo "Unable to select roomsbooking: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}
// get All the rooms with id_item = 1 (is room 201) and MAY.
$sql="SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE id_item = '1' AND month(the_date)='5'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$room201 .= '<td>'.$row['id_state'].'</td>';
}
// get All the rooms with id_item = 2 (is room 104) and MAY.
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE id_item = '2' AND month(the_date)='5'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
$Room104 .= '<td>'.$row['id_state'].'</td>';
}
echo '
<table class="">  
<tfoot>
<th>Days</th>';
 for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) //statement to display month days.
{
echo "<th>" . $i . "</th>";
} 
echo '</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b>Room201:</b></td>'.$room201 .'
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Room104:</b></td>'.$Room104 .'
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>';
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

[image: Present result]
[image: Desirable]

Comment: So, is there an item in the database for the day?  You just say "select *" so we can't see that structure.  I would assume that you'll want to compare the value of this item (perhaps it's called "day") against the $i variable in your loop, and print something if they match. :)

Comment: Yes there is. The table has 6 columns (cust_id,id_item, surname, id_state, id_booking , the_date).The "id_state" that takes two different values '1' or '4'. See the images above. The first image echos all values in a row, but i need to echo them in the exact day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code.  Note that there are some pretty serious things that should be done that I didn't address, but I think this will get you started:  http://pastebin.com/Fvs8A49n